# Show that $ \sum_{i = m}^{n} a_{i} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-m+1} a_{m-1+j}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$ \sum_{i = m}^{n} a_{i} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-m+1} a_{m-1+j}$$

I'm struggling to show the right hand side of this indexshift, how can derive the right hand side from the left hand side?
I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: For a rigorous proof you could do an induction over n, starting with n=m.

Comment: Or show that it's just a change of variables $j  = i - m + 1$.